# The tower of path algebras associated to a tower of finite dimensional $C^*$-algebras is isomorphic to the original tower

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, banach-algebras

Let $A_0\subseteq A_1\subseteq...$ be an infinite tower of unital inclusions of finite dimensional $C^*$-algebras and $B_0\subseteq B_1\subseteq ...$ be its associated infinite tower of path algebras. Then how to show that these two towers are tower isomorphic ?